# In Python, kick off an async function and return early

Tags: python

I have a function in python that should kick off an asynchronous 'slow' function, and return before that 'slow' function completes.

```
async def doSomethingSlowButReturnQuickly():
  asyncio.create_task(_mySlowFunction())

  return "Returning early! Slow function is still running."

async def _mySlowFunction():
  // Do some really slow stuff that isn't blocking for our other function.
```

Running this still seems to cause the 'return' to not happen until AFTER my async task has completed.

How do I correct this?

*(And apologies, this is day #2 writing Python)*

Comment: Use multi-threading, not async functions.

Comment: @Barmar - can you provide extra context on why multi-threading is preferred over async tasks here?

Comment: Actually, the answer is to just not declare the function `async`.

Comment: @Barmar - which function? And my understanding is that async functions can only be called from within async functions.

Comment: I don't think either of them needs to be async. Just calling `asyncio.create_task()` runs that task without waiting for it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you asked, but you can run code in an [async executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) and continue while it is still running:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep


def blocking_code():
    sleep(2)
    print('inner')
    return 'result'


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(blocking_code)
        print('after')
        print(future.result())
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
after
inner
result
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a dull answer, but if you want to stick with `asyncio`, I would advise to be sure using `await` in every`async def` functions.

```py
async def doSomethingSlowButReturnQuickly(): 
    task = asyncio.create_task(_mySlowFunction())

    # must await something here!

    return "Returning early! Slow function is still running."

async def _mySlowFunction():

    # must await something here
```

If you don't need to get the slow function return value, why don't you directly call the two coroutines from a main function?

```py
import asyncio 

async def doSomethingSlowButReturnQuickly(): 

    await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # must await something here! 

    return "Returning early! Slow function is still running."

async def _mySlowFunction():

    await asyncio.sleep(10) # must await something here

async def main():
    tasks = [_mySlowFunction(), doSomethingSlowButReturnQuickly()]
    asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```